# Enviar conteúdo de um index para um edit através do AJAX com .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Estou criando uma tela de aprovação e quando o usuário clicar em reprovar irá aparecer um pop-up pra ele descrever o motivo da recusa ... O problema é que não estou conseguindo enviar via AJAX as informações inseridas no pop-up, a tela de aprovação juntamente com o pop-up fica no index e eu desejo enviar essa informação para uma outra controller.

```
  function pegarInformacoes() {

        var mensagem = document.getElementById("message-text").value;
        console.log(mensagem);
        var id = document.getElementById("buscarid").textContent;
        console.log(id);
        EnviaDados(mensagem, id);

    }
```

na var mensagem ele pega o conteúdo obtido na caixinha de resposta,e no id ele pega o id da coluna.

```
 function EnviaDados(mensagemreprov,numeroid) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/AprovacaoMudanca/Index',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { "Motivo": mensagemreprov, "AprovacaoMudancaId": numeroid  },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                alert("sucesso!");

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (XMLHttpRequest.status === 0) {
                    alert(' Check Your Network.');
                } else if (XMLHttpRequest.status === 404) {
                    alert('Requested URL not found.');
                } else if (XMLHttpRequest.status === 500) {
                    alert('Internal Server Error.');
                } else {
                    alert('Unknow Error.\n' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Você tem que descrever melhor o erro que está acontecendo. Não há nenhum problema aparente com o seu código.

Comment: Por que o post para a rota `/AprovacaoMudanca/Edit/VariavelComiD` não funciona? Você tem um método com a anotação `[HttpPost]` respondendo a ela em sua controller?